# Fastest way to check if a number is summable from two lists of integers?

Tags: java, loops, math

So, I have a list of integers. I need to find out if a specific number can be added by any two numbers from a list(non-unique numbers).
What I have so far:

```
boolean cs = false;
    t:
    for(Integer i1 : primes) {
        for(Integer i2 : primes) {
            if(i1 + i2 == i) {
                cs = true;
                break t;
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, as this list gets higher(because each time there are no two sums, it must find and create a new sum to keep the sequence going), this function takes exponentially longer to execute. Are there any ways to prevent such an issue? As this function gets into the thousands, it more or less just stops due to how long it takes.

Comment: subtract i1 from i and check if the result is contained in i2 using a binary search or a HashSet.

Comment: Sorry for sounding ignorant, but google is a bit shy as to what a binary search is?

Comment: That brings it down to n log n. If you're checking a block of numbers, say verifying Goldbach up to n, you'll be better of with a sieve.

Comment: FYI, I believe @SpiderPig's suggestion requires your list to be ordered, and ideally unique.

Comment: java.util.Array and Collections both have a binary search method.

Comment: The numbers are unique, just not in order. I'm not verifying Goldbachs, but trying to use it to generate primes.

Comment: A binary search is simply searching the middle element of an *ordered* collection. It will fail either too low--meaning you need only search the high half--or fail too high--meaning you need to search the low half. Keep repeating until you get what you need.

Comment: @SpiderPig You said java has this built in? I tried using the contains method, but that doesn't appear to change much. Or will I be better off on my own? The issue with sorting, is I want this to be as fast as possible, and considering this list is changing every 1/5th of a ms, that doesn't work to well.

Comment: You need to use java.util.Collections.binarySearch, not contains. The contains method is slow except on HashSets.

Comment: @SpiderPig According to the javadoc, it needs to be sorted. Any ideas on how to do this with little time lost?

Comment: You could generate the numbers such that they are sorted to begin with. or you can use java.util.Arrays.sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic implementation of sorting and binary-searching a list of ints.

```
   import  java.util.ArrayList;
   import  java.util.Arrays;
   import  java.util.Collections;
/**
   <P>{@code java OrderIntListXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class OrderIntListXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
      int[] aiNums = new int[] {1, 11, 29, 12, 13, 19, 7, 2, 6, 16, 10, 15, 112, 18, 20, 3, 8, 5, 9, 14};

      System.out.println("Unsorted: " + Arrays.toString(aiNums));

      ArrayList<Integer> alNums = new ArrayList<Integer>(aiNums.length);
      for(int i : aiNums)  {
         alNums.add(i);
      }
      Collections.sort(alNums);

      System.out.println("Sorted: " + Arrays.toString(alNums.toArray()));

      int ixOf12 = Collections.<Integer>binarySearch(alNums, 12);

      System.out.println("Index of number 12: " + ixOf12);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java OrderIntListXmpl
Unsorted: [1, 11, 29, 12, 13, 19, 7, 2, 6, 16, 10, 15, 112, 18, 20, 3, 8, 5, 9, 14]
Sorted: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 29, 112]
Index of number 12: 10
```

Javadoc for [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) and [binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29)

Answer (score 1):

First, sort the list.

Then start two cursors into the list, one at either end.  In a loop, sum the two values under the cursors.  If it is less than your desired total, advance the left (smaller) cursor one step to the right (the "larger" direction.)  If the sum is larger, advance the right (smaller) cursor one step to the left.

If there is a pair that sums to your desired total, this will find it.  It takes `O(n log n)` time to sort the list, and `O(n)` time to run the cursor loop.  Overall it is therefore `O(n log n)`, which will hopefully be fast enough for your needs.

**EDIT**

Actually, there's a linear time, linear space algorithm to do this.  Suppose your target number is `k`.  For each integer `i` in your list, insert `k - i` into a hash set.  Then check if `i` is already in the set.  If it is, then it must be because `k - i` was already encountered earlier in the list.  This is probably the algorithm @SpiderPig hinted at.

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying this [example](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/TwoSumFast.java.html) from Princeton Prof Robert Segwick. it finds two numbers which sum to 0 .

There are two algos, one which you are using [Brute force](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/TwoSum.java.html) with O(n2). Another one nLog(n) which follows sorting and negating the another number [example](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/TwoSumFast.java.html) .

Answer (score 0):

To make it as fast as possible you should use arrays.
Here is an example.

```
class Primes {
    static int[] primeSieve(int max) {
        boolean[] sieve = new boolean[max];
        for(int i = 2; i < sieve.length; i++) {
            sieve[i] = true;
        }
        int prime = 2;
        while(prime*prime < max) {
            for(int i = prime*2; i < max; i += prime) {
                sieve[i] = false;
            }
            prime++;
            while(!sieve[prime]) prime++;
        }
        int primesSize = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if(sieve[i]) primesSize++;
        }
        int[] primes = new int[primesSize];
        for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if(sieve[i]) primes[j++] = i;
        }
        return primes;
    }

    static boolean isSummable(int num, int[] primes) {
        for(int i = 0; i < primes.length && primes[i] < num; i++) {
            int j = num-primes[i];
            int index = java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(primes, j);
            if(index >= 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] primes = primeSieve(1000000);
        System.out.println(primes.length);

        System.out.println(isSummable(575210, primes));
    }
}
```